# [variable].AddEventListener in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am very new to coding. Below is a piece of JS code i am struggling to understand:

```
var btnContainer = document.getElementbyId(“linkcontainer”);
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsbyClassName(“btn”);
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
btns.addEventListener(“click”, function(){
var current = document.getElementsbyClassName(“active”);
current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(‘active’, “”);
 this.className += ‘active’;
});}
```

What difference does the `[i]` make in

> btns[i].AddEventListener??

What is it exactly and what if there was no “i” in between the brackets? Also current[0]. It’s probably a stupid question, but please help me understand.

Answer (score 3):

First of all there are no stupid question but only stupid answers.

In your code you get a list of DOM elements stored in an array called 'btns', then you iterate it with a loop.

So `btns[i]` allow you to retrieves the elements at the `i` position (It's important to note that array start at 0 in Javascript).

Example:

```js
var fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana'];

console.log(fruits[0])
console.log(fruits[1])
```

So if you don't use the `[i]` you will iterate on the array itself and not on the element stored in it.

Answer (score 1):

As the name of the method [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) suggests, this queries the `DOM` and returns an array like object that contain multiple elements with the class name that was specified.

`btns` - will be an array that contains one or more elements.

To access a specific element from the array, you access it using the index of the current iteration.

`btns[1]` - Gives you access to the 2nd element in the list.

[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - is used to bind a event handler to a single element. You cannot directly use this on array of objects.

```
// query the DOM for element with id - linkcontainer
var btnContainer = document.getElementbyId(“linkcontainer”);
// query the DOM for elements with className - btn
// This can return multiple elements, so btns will be 
// as array like object of elements
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName(“btn”);

// iterate over the array that was just queried for
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {

  // bind a click event for each element in the array
  btns[i].addEventListener(“click”, function() {
    // query the dom for elements with className - active
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName(“active”);

    // access the first element and replace the active class 
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(‘active’, “”);

    // add the active class to the element that was clicked
    this.className += ‘active’;
  });
}
```

The way I see it you will have to remove the `active` class for all the elements instead of just the first entity. A slightly better way to improve this code would be is

```
var btnContainer = document.getElementbyId(“linkcontainer”);
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName(“btn”);

btns.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener(“click”, function() {
    // query the dom for elements with className - active
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName(“active”);

    current.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.classList.remove('active');
    });

    this.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: The function's name is `getElementsByClassName`, with an upper case **B**.

Comment: @Titus Good catch. Missed that.

Answer (score 0):

As the other posters have mentioned, your code `var btns = btnContainer.getElementsbyClassName(“btn”);` should return an array of DOM elements so in your for loop, `btns[i]` will retrieve the specific element at index i of `btns` as i goes from 0 to `btns.length`. Removing the i will retrieve the entire array on each iteration.

To your second question: `current` is exactly the same thing as `btns`, an array of DOM elements so `current[0]` will retrieve the first element in this array.